# Where am I going wrong with this function to find a Sphenic number?

Tags: c++, function

```
bool isSphenic (int num){
    int initial_num = num;
    int product = 1;
    int prime_count = 0;
    int i = 2;

    while (num > 1){
        if(num % i == 0){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                num = num/i;
                product = product * i;
                prime_count = prime_count + 1;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    if(product == initial_num && prime_count == 3 ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can't figure out where the lag is coming from. I'm using it on a list of about 100 numbers from 1 to 100. It correctly identifies the sphenic numbers but it takes minutes, or crashes...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the input you are using.

Comment: your code is incomplete, so it is hard to say where it spends its time, but it seems like you are calling `isPrime` again and again for same parameters when you run the posted method for numbers from 1 to 100

Comment: also you do not have to compute the full prime factorization. Once you know that the number has more than 3 prime factors you can stop the loop.

Comment: What measures of debugging have you done so far? Did you use a debugger? Print output? A profiler like gprof? But I agree with the other guy, you probably call `isPrime` far too often, and `isPrime` does not do something like storing what input it had so far (which is feasible if hundred is a realistic input).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the function is that it does not divide a given number by a prime number until the number is not divisible by the prime number.

For example for the number equal to 4 the division occurs inly once by 2 and then I is increased but num is not equal to 1. It is equal to 2 after the division.

So the function has an infinite loop.

The function can look similar to the function presented in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

bool isSphenic ( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int DISTINCT_PRIMES = 3;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned int product = 1;


    for ( unsigned int tmp = n, i = 2; count < DISTINCT_PRIMES && tmp != 1; i++ )
    {
        if ( tmp % i == 0 )
        {
            ++count;
            product *= i;
            while ( tmp % i == 0 ) tmp /= i;
        }
    }

    return count == DISTINCT_PRIMES && product == n; 
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 200;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( isSphenic( i ) ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
30 42 66 70 78 102 105 110 114 130 138 154 165 170 174 182 186 190 195
```

Pay attention to that there is no need to call the function `sPrime` as you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I see the infinite loop problem now. I really didn't think about the non-sphenic numbers...